# how update video while taping on flip button and rotate button in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-animation

```
//@dart=2.9

import 'dart:io';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/painting.dart';
import 'package:photomanager/Pages/Preview.dart';
import 'package:video_player/video_player.dart';

class CropScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const CropScreen({Key key, this.File}) : super(key: key);

  final String File;

  @override
  _CropScreenState createState() => _CropScreenState();
}

class _CropScreenState extends State<CropScreen> {
  VideoPlayerController controller;
  Future<void> futureController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    controller = VideoPlayerController.file(File(widget.File));
    controller.setLooping(true);
    futureController = controller.initialize();
    controller.value.duration;
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    controller.dispose();
    // TODO: implement dispose
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.black,
        bottomNavigationBar: BottomAppBar(
          color: Colors.black,
          child: Row(children: <Widget>[
            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
            ),
            Container(
                height: 80,
                width: 56,
                child: InkWell(
                  onTap: () {
                    Navigator.push(
                      context,
                      MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Preview()),
                    );
                  },
//buttons for croping in different size
                  child: Column(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                      children: [
                        Image.asset(
                          'assets/Crop/ic_default.png',
                          height: 56,
                          width: 56,
                        ),
                      ]),
                )),
            SizedBox(width: 20),
            Container(
                height: 77,
                width: 56,
                child: InkWell(
                  onTap: () {
                    Navigator.push(
                      context,
                      MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => CropScreen()),
                    );
                  },
                  child: Column(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                      children: [
                        Image.asset(
                          'assets/Crop/ic_squre.png',
                          height: 56,
                          width: 56,
                        ),
                      ]),
                )),
            SizedBox(width: 20),
            Container(
                height: 77,
                width: 56,
                child: InkWell(
                  onTap: () {
                    Navigator.push(
                      context,
                      MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => CropScreen()),
                    );
                  },
                  child: Column(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                      children: [
                        Image.asset(
                          'assets/Crop/ic_4_5.png',
                          height: 77,
                          width: 56,
                        ),
                      ]),
                )),
            SizedBox(width: 20),
            Container(
                height: 77,
                width: 56,
                child: InkWell(
                  onTap: () {
                    Navigator.push(
                      context,
                      MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => CropScreen()),
                    );
                  },
                  child: Column(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                      children: [
                        Image.asset(
                          'assets/Crop/ic_2_3.png',
                          height: 77,
                          width: 56,
                        ),
                      ]),
                )),
          ]),
        ),
        body: Column(
            children: [
          Container(
            height: 404,
            width: 251,
            child:
            FutureBuilder(
              future: futureController,
              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
                  return Center(
                    child: AspectRatio(
                      aspectRatio: controller.value.aspectRatio,
                      child: VideoPlayer(controller),
                    ),
                  );
                } else {
                  return Center(
                    child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                  );
                }
              },
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox(height: 22.47),
          Container(
            height: 50,
            color: Colors.black,
              child :Center(
              child:Row(children:[
                Padding(padding: EdgeInsetsDirectional.fromSTEB(100, 0, 0, 0)),


// flip the video right to left 

                InkWell(
                  onTap: () {},
                  child: ClipRRect(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
                    child: Image.asset('assets/Crop/flip.png',
                        // width: 110.0, height: 110.0
                      ),
                  ),
                ),Padding(padding: EdgeInsetsDirectional.fromSTEB(100, 0, 0, 0)),


//I want to rotate 90degree while on tap on this 
                InkWell(
                  onTap: () {},
                  child: ClipRRect(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
                    child: Image.asset("assets/Crop/ic_undo.png",
                        // width: 110.0, height: 110.0
                      ),
                  ),
                ),
               ])),
          ),
          Container(
            // color: Colors.white,
            padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 0, 20, 0),
            alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
            child: Column(children: [
              FloatingActionButton(
                mini: true,
                backgroundColor: Colors.yellow,
                onPressed: () {
                  if (controller.value.isPlaying) {
                    setState(() {
                      controller.pause();
                    });
                  } else {
                    setState(() {
                      controller.play();
                    });
                  }
                },
                // child:Text(controller.value.size);
                child: Icon(
                    controller.value.isPlaying ? Icons.pause : Icons.play_arrow,
                    color: Colors.black),
              ),
            ]),
          ),
        ]));
  }
}
```

In above code  i wnat to do rotation of the video and fliping of video where i have written above, and also in cropping section i get some difficulty so please help me out,or i want update every time with single code but i can't know how to do that

controller =  call the video which is selected in previous page